# How do I profile code for cache misses to optimise C code?

Tags: c, optimization, caching, memory, memory-management

I'm optimising some C code and I want to minimise the cache misses I get. Before that, I'd like to identify parts where I'm getting the most cache misses.

What tools can I use to help me identify (perhaps at the granularity of blocks) where I'm getting the most misses?

Comment: On what platform? If you are on Linux try `valgrind` and its `cachegrind`.

Comment: Caches algorithms are not the same on all processors. Optimizing cache misses is inherently platform dependent though optimizing it on one platform can also speed things up on other platforms. AFAIK, tools like `valgrind` and `cachegrind` made assumption on the algorithm use which is not very realistic (but not very bad either). If you want practical results, then you need to track hardware counters which are mostly platform dependent (more specifically, they are dependant of the specific CPU microarchitecture used). Thus, please share more details about the actual platform used.

Comment: Thanks, cachegrind it is for me. I was looking for metrics to experiment with cache-oblivious algorithms, and cachegrind's execution environment gets me the data I wanted.